# NoClassDefFoundError using bluetooth in java

Tags: java, bluetooth, bluecove

I asked a question earlier here: [NoClassDefFoundError with bluecove's javax.microedition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41198909/noclassdeffounderror-with-bluecoves-javax-microedition)
but got no responses.

I am trying to run some java code (Server.java) that requires bluetooth, so I installed the bluecove-2.1.0.jar file in C:\Program Files\Java.

I compile my code with `javac -cp "C:\Program Files\Java\bluecove-2.1.0.jar";. Server.java` and run it with `java Server -cp "C:\Program Files\Java\bluecove-2.1.0.jar"`

It compiles successfully, but when I run it, I get the error:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try  again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/microedition/io/Connection
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.microedition.io.Connection
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 7 more
```

Any ideas where i've gone wrong?

EDIT: Following Minus' answer, to fix the error that followed, I also needed to use a different .jar file which I downloaded from http://snapshot.bluecove.org/distribution/download/2.1.1-SNAPSHOT/2.1.1-SNAPSHOT.63/

Comment: what happens when you call the classpath arg before the java class (ie java -cp "blah.bluecove" Server)

Comment: @mcalex I get the error `Error: Could not find or load main class Server`

Comment: @w1nter, thank you very much! That 2.1.1-SNAPSHOT link and the `intelbth_x64.dll` in it solves my problem. The latest official release 2.1.0 (in 2008) is plainly too old.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the .dll is not loaded correctly.

The library should contain a .dll that will be saved on disk and loaded, maybe the program cannot save the .dll to disk or cannot read it.

Extract the .dll and follow [bluecove installation instructions](https://code.google.com/archive/p/bluecove/wikis/Documentation.wiki) on *Native Library location*.

For example:

Create a directory `c:\blue`, and a directory `blue\lib`.

Put the files like this:

```
C:\blue\Sever.java
C:\blue\Sever.class
C:\blue\[bluecove_native_library].dll
C:\blue\lib\bluecove-2.1.0.jar
```

Open a cmd (Command Prompt) on c:\blue

Try to run the app like this:

```
java -cp .;lib\bluecove-2.1.0.jar -Dbluecove.native.resource=false Server
```

This way you will have both Server.class and bluecove-2.1.0.jar in classpath and the DLL in path (since on Windows the current dir is in path).

Comment: I understand why that would be the problem, but where is this .dll file you talk of that I need to extract

Comment: Should be inside the jar. Jars are just zip so you can simply extract content from them with any unzip tool (7zip , izarch ... any).

Comment: Ok so I extracted the files from the .jar file. Using the installation instructions, I am doing `java Server -cp "/path/to/jar" -Dbluecove.native.path=/your/path` should /your/path be `C:/path/to/dir` or `C:/path/to/dll` or even `"C:/path/to/dir"` or `C:\path\to\dir` or some other variant?

Comment: It's sufficient that you extract the .dll and put it in your PATH, then you can still run the application using the jar.

Answer (score 1):

Add a current folder to a classpath **(.;)** and make sure that your code is in a **package-name** folder.
So if your server has a package name :
**mypackage**
make sure that your class code is in a **/mypackage** directory
than go to a parent folder to **/mypackage** and call:

java -cp ".;C:\Program Files\Java\bluecove-2.1.0.jar" mypackage.Server

Comment: Ok so I am in a directory with Server.class in it. I created a directory called serverPackage, and put Server.class into it. Now, from the current directory, i.e. the parent directory of serverPackage, I called `java -cp ".;C:\Program Files\Java\bluecove-2.1.0.jar" serverPackage.Server` Is that what you meant? It gave the error `Error: Could not find or load main class Server`

Comment: Is your package name in Server class also called serverPackage?
This folder name has to be the same as your package name for Server class, you use a full package name for the call

Comment: Ohh I see, my class file was stand alone, i've never used packages before. That should not be necessary if I just have a .java file sitting about which i've compiled through command line right? I've just had a fiddle about with packages but now I cannot even "find or load main class Server" when trying to compile it - best leave that problem for another day and stick with simple .java .class files if possible

Comment: having said that, and just to make things more awkward, I use bluej to do my projects, which I think does this whole package thing anyway.

Comment: Java requires you to use packages, if you do not state its name the default package name (.) will be assumed. As long as you are doing a test Hello World application you do not need to worry about packages but beyond that you should always use them.